# How to use spring cloud sleuth for RabbitListener and RabbitTemplate

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I want to send RabbitMQ messages tracking event to Zipkin with using spring cloud sleuth, After many research I found some configuration added recently to spring in order to manage it you can find in [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java), But unfortunately there is not any  documentation that explains how can we configure it, I tried many ways but I couldn't send tracking events to Zipkin.

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration you're referring to is for the instrumentation of messaging systems, not for sending traces to zipkin using a messaging system.

You should look at this [auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin2/ZipkinAutoConfiguration.java), and especially this [sender config](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin2/sender/ZipkinRabbitSenderConfiguration.java).

What you want to do has also been documented here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.0.x/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_sleuth_with_zipkin_over_rabbitmq_or_kafka

You should only need to add `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin` and `spring-rabbit` to your dependencies. If you want to change the default queue (which is `zipkin`), then you'll need to add `spring.zipkin.rabbitmq.queue` to your properties.